# Python import methods from different packages

Tags: python-3.x, import, package

I have a folder structure as below:

[image]

Now 1 want to run `sep.py` (tor/sep.py) which calls the `te.py` (t1/te.py) file which internally has dependency on `ut.py` (t1/t3/ut.py) file
so when I run the command

**python -m tor.sep it gives the following error**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", mod_spec)

File "C:\Software\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)

File "C:\Local\Python\tempython\tor\sep.py", line 8, in 
    from t1.te import te

File "C:\Local\Python\tempython\t1\te.py", line 7, in 
    from t3.ut import ut

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 't3'**

I am new to python and this package importing part has me confused for internal dependency
So basically as far my understanding goes if I call the files inside a subpackage it will work but as soon as I try calling calling some file1 from file2 in another pacakge and also file1 has dependency on a file3 which is a subpackage of the place where file1 is kept I am unable to do that can some one help me with that

Comment: I need to loot at your import.

Comment: inside the te.py **from t3.ut import ut** and inside the sep.py file the import is **from t1.te import te** the file name(module name) and the class inside them have the same name